# iPhone image resource - 1024 maximum, 2048 pixels @2x?

Tags: iphone, image, retina-display

The restriction of 1024x1024 as the largest image for an iPhone is a problem with iPhone 4. However if an @2x image is used with maximum dimensions of 2048x2048 everything looks equally good on the 4 as it does on a 3 - tried and tested in simulator and device. Question is, does the image dimension restriction relate to the UIImage or the resource that it contains? I can't imagine resources of more than 1024 pixels are discouraged with the 960 pixel height of the screen.

The right answer is really to use tiles so that things look even better, but the deadline for for this deliverable is too close - it's a future thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `UIImage` class reference:

> You should avoid creating UIImage
>   objects that are greater than 1024 x
>   1024 in size. Besides the large amount
>   of memory such an image would consume,
>   you may run into problems when using
>   the image as a texture in OpenGL ES or
>   when drawing the image to a view or
>   layer. This size restriction does not
>   apply if you are performing code-based
>   manipulations, such as resizing an
>   image larger than 1024 x 1024 pixels
>   by drawing it to a bitmap-backed
>   graphics context. In fact, you may
>   need to resize an image in this manner
>   (or break it into several smaller
>   images) in order to draw it to one of
>   your views.

That is, views are rendered and composited with the iPhone's GPU. If your view, for example, overrides `drawRect` and tries to render a very big `UIImage` you might run into problems. Newer generation iDevices, such as iPad and iPhone 4 support bigger textures than 1024x1024 (2048x2048 I think).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realise there was a restriction, I'm using an image 15198 × 252 as the scrolling landscape in Scramble... works really well, though I must say I did have reservations before I tried it out!